# Insert same information to all stores

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I have a lot of stores in my database and i have some similar data that has to be in all of the stores. Here is my example:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[stores] 
            ([identifiers], 
             [sales_price], 
             [discount],  
             [store]) 
VALUES      ('9788276911',  
             99, 
             20, 
             'store121')
```

Is it any ways i can insert this data in all stores and not only 'store121'? Just looking for a easy way out here really :)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you don't have your store names in table, you should create a table and populate it with names (copy/paste from your Excel).

If we assume your names are in table `StoreNames`, column `Store`, you can use a query like this to insert same data to table `stores` for all your stores

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[stores] 
            ([identifiers], 
             [sales_price], 
             [discount],  
             [store]) 
SELECT '9788276911',  
        99, 
        20,
        [store]
FROM StoreNames
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8852d/2)**

Comment: Ok i actually have a Store table with NAME but the problem is that this DB is much more complex than that, and if i could just write the stores myself it would make stuff a lot more easy. Because i dont want the similar data for all stores, just 15 of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
update stores
set identifiers = '9788276911',
    sales_price = 99,
    discount = 20
```

will update all records.

Comment: I need to insert the same data to all the stores in the discount table: store1, store2, store3 etc. Will updating do this?

Comment: No, this not only update existing records. Do it in a loop or use a self-tailored insert statement like this: `insert into t (col1, col2) values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)`

Comment: @op do u want to insert it into discount table from store table?

Comment: No i just want to insert the same data into 15 different store names.

Comment: @Lebowski Where do you get your stores names from?

Comment: A excel document. I only have 15 stores, but i have a lot of similar data that all of them should have in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution proposed by @Nenad Zivkovic, you can also enumerate your 15 stores in a row constructor instead of reading the stores table if that makes it easier for you:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[stores] 
            ([identifiers], 
             [sales_price], 
             [discount],  
             [store]) 
SELECT '9788276911',  
        99, 
        20,
        [store]
FROM  (values
  ('store1'),('store2'),('store3'),('store4')) x(store)
```